# Android change image resource of Imagebutton

Tags: java, android, multithreading

This is the code I'm working on:

```
    if(place.equalsIgnoreCase("Department Store")){

        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                t = Toast.makeText(Map.this, "Department Store", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                t.show();
            }
        };
        thread.start();

    }
```

Basically, what I wanna do is when user clicks on the button and if it satisfies the condition (i.e. "department store"), the imagebutton will change its image resource for 5 seconds and then returns to its default image resource. How can I do this? I'm thinking of using thread as per my post above, but I can't seem to think of nice way to implement it. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @blackbelt I can't think of ways how or where to put the duration for the new image resource and after that change back to original resource.

Comment: use handler with postDelayed

Comment: @Dunkey : you can change image on Button click and also set Handler for changing it to prev image after 5 secs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Handler().postDelayed()` for this:

```
// Original image
// This could have been set in your layout file. 
// In this case, you can skip this statement.

imageButton. setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
             R.drawable.some_drawable_id));


someButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (someCondition) {

            // Change image
            imageButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.some_drawable_that_will_stay_for_5_secs));

            // Handler
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    // Revert back to original image
                    imageButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                                                R.drawable.some_drawable_id));            
                }
           }, 5000L);    // 5000 milliseconds(5 seconds) delay
        }
    }
});
```